# Unity Network.Connect() returns no error

Tags: networking, network-programming, unity-game-engine, network-connection

I'm trying to create an online game, It works in my computer, and even in two different computers in my house. But it does not connect to room of other players.

I'm testing by trying to connect a closed room, naturally it does not connect, but still the NetworkConnectionError returns "NoError" , and the OnFailedToConnect() function is never called.

My code is this:

```
if(GUI.Button(Rect,"Connect"))
{
    var error = Network.Connect(element);
    printConsoleEntry("Connection attempt : " + error);
}
```

which prints `"Connection attempt : NoError"`.

But at some point, I see in the "real console", in the unity editor window,

> The connection request to
>   192.168.x.x:26500 failed. Are you sure the server can be connected to?

But it does not show immediately I press the "connect" button. It waits a little. And it only shows once, out of a 100 presses, So is there some kind of yielding?

I also tried to yield the error in a coroutine like :

```
var error = Network.Connect(element);
yield error;
printConsoleEntry("Bağlantı denemesi : "+error);
```

it always returns NoError.

so where is the error?
How can I see it?